# Remove XML Nodes for matching attribute condition in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I want to remove all the nodes in XML datatype column;  matching the attribute condition for all the records.For example `<resource>` node which has attribute "type" whose value is like '%audio%'.

Input:

```
<metadata Item="1234" version="5" packageVersion="5" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
  <contents>
    <content version="0" href="content_es-mx_en-us.xml" lang="es-mx" altlang="en-us">
      <resources />
    </content>
    <content version="3" href="content_en-us.xml" lang="en-us">
      <resources>
        <resource type="image/svg" href="girlwateringtomatoes2.svg" />
        <resource type="audio/ogg" href="Audio/115988A_Sound1.ogg" />
        <resource type="audio/mp4" href="Audio/115988A_Sound1.m4a" />  
      </resources>
    </content>
  </contents>
  <references />
  <brailleEncodings />
</metadata>
```

Output:

```
<metadata Item="1234" version="5" packageVersion="5" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
  <contents>
    <content version="0" href="content_es-mx_en-us.xml" lang="es-mx" altlang="en-us">
      <resources />
    </content>
    <content version="3" href="content_en-us.xml" lang="en-us">
      <resources>
        <resource type="image/svg" href="girlwateringtomatoes2.svg" /> 
      </resources>
    </content>
  </contents>
  <references />
  <brailleEncodings />
</metadata>
```

Here is the query which i have tried but didn't work.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS NS)
Update dbo.TableX 
SET [XML].modify('delete /NS:metadata/NS:contents/NS:content[2]/resources/resource[@type != "image/svg"]')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this, it's a namespaces issue...

```
declare @x table(myXML xml);
insert into @x values(
'<metadata Item="1234" version="5" packageVersion="5" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2">
  <contents>
    <content version="0" href="content_es-mx_en-us.xml" lang="es-mx" altlang="en-us">
      <resources />
    </content>
    <content version="3" href="content_en-us.xml" lang="en-us">
      <resources>
        <resource type="image/svg" href="girlwateringtomatoes2.svg" />
        <resource type="audio/ogg" href="Audio/115988A_Sound1.ogg" />
        <resource type="audio/mp4" href="Audio/115988A_Sound1.m4a" />  
      </resources>
    </content>
  </contents>
  <references />
  <brailleEncodings />
</metadata>');

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2')
Update @x 
SET [myXML].modify('delete /metadata/contents/content[2]/resources/resource[@type != "image/svg"]')

SELECT * FROM @x;
```

Comment: yup - alternatively add the `NS:` prefix to ech node down the chain.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove everything that has `type` like `audio` you could use [`contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' AS NS)
Update TableX 
SET [XML].modify('delete /NS:metadata/NS:contents/NS:content[2]/NS:resources/NS:resource[contains(@type, "audio")]');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447855?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Output:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2" Item="1234" version="5" packageVersion="5">
   <contents>
      <content version="0" href="content_es-mx_en-us.xml" lang="es-mx" altlang="en-us">
         <resources />
      </content>
      <content version="3" href="content_en-us.xml" lang="en-us">
         <resources>
            <resource type="image/svg" href="girlwateringtomatoes2.svg" />
         </resources>
      </content>
   </contents>
   <references />
   <brailleEncodings />
</metadata>
```

---

Alternatively in any position in XML document:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p2' )
Update TableX 
SET [XML].modify('delete //resources/resource[contains(@type, "audio")]');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/447864?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>